# Get profile id using username in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to catch the username entered in the login page and get corresponding profileid(the column in DB) and show it in another page my DAL code is

```
public DataTable getall()
   {
       SqlConnection conn1 = Generic.DBConnection.OpenConnection();
       DataTable dt=new DataTable();
       try
       {
             string sql = "Select * from Profile_Master";
             SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(sql,conn1);
             SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);
           sqlDa.Fill(dt);


       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           throw ex;
       }
       return dt;
   }
```

My UI

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                ProfileMasterDAL dal = new ProfileMasterDAL();
                dt1 = dal.getall();
                if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["sdds"] = dt1.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
                    Session["EmailId"] = dt1.Rows[0]["EmailID"].ToString();
                    Session["pid"] = dt1.Rows[0]["NewidColumn"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("~/Myhome.aspx");
```

but i am able to get the first value in the DB not the corresponding value for the username?

Comment: I would suspect the lack of a `WHERE` clause in your query is causing you to only get the first row. Try putting something like `WHERE Profile_Master_Username = username` in the SqlCommand

Comment: But i am not sending the username in getall()

Comment: What if i want to get some more values based on username?

Comment: You need to pass the relevant data through to the query otherwise how are you going to filter it? I would suggest a simple string parameter. As for the extra data, there is no reason why you don't have a really complex query that returns all sorts of data from various tables. Alternatively, try using something like the Entity Framework as your DAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement has 10 rows. and the required row for you is in 5th position. 
when you say  dt1.Rows[0]["FirstName"] you will get only the first record but not the 5th record.

If you want to make this work, add where condition to your select statement, which returns exactly one required row for you.

something like..

"select * from Profile_Master PM Where PM.UserName = @username"

where @username is your input from login page. And is unique in the database Table